# Image of Button does not appear on Contextmenu

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, contextmenu, word-2013

I have add a button to the standart context menu (right click menu). This works fine so far. But i get some trouble by adding a image in front of the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuText">
      <button id="startResearch" label="Start Research!" insertBeforeMso="HyperlinkInsert" onAction="startResearchClick"            showImage="true" visible="true" image="pack://application:,,,/Resources/magnifying_glass.png"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> image="pack://application:,,,/Resources/magnifying_glass.png"/>

You can't specify the resource or image path that way.

There are two main ways for specifying images in the Ribbon XML markup:

1. The **loadImage** callback in the  element for loading images and the **image** attribute for specifying image IDs at the controls. By using this technique, you can write a single callback procedure that returns all the images your customization needs, without having to write each individual control's getImage callback. Note that the loadImage callback is not called again when you call the Ribbon's Invalidate method or InvalidateControl method. For the controls that need to change images dynamically at run time, use the getImage callback.
2. The the **getImage** attribute at the controls. Allows to load/change images dynamically.

You can read more about that in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Better to provide solution than pointing to a solution over MSDN

Comment: I don't understand those who downvotes real answers... Stop the world, I'll leave...

Comment: The solution is described in depth in the articles I mentioned above. It is not a good idea to copy and paste a lot print pages there.

Comment: Thank you very much @EugeneAstafiev .This will help me tomorrow :)